# How to access the number of threads currently reading/writing form the userspace?

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel

I have written a module where a user can read or write to a proc file - how do I determine the number of threads in a user process that is reading or writing in kernel-level programming?

Comment: Do you mean how a kernel module can determine the number of threads in a user space process that read or write its /proc file(s)?

Comment: No, not exactly. Rather, once a process reads/writes to my proc (via my module) how can I nab the pid and find the number of threads associated with that pid, all of this being done in kernel space.

Comment: I saw you got an answer on SU.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `current` as a pointer to the current task (current `task_struct`) inside your read/write function:

```
#include <linux/sched.h>

struct task_struct * t;
for (t = next_thread(current); t != current; t = next_thread(t)) {
    // do the stuff
}
```