# List all threads within the current process?

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel

I'm trying to implement a syscall which allows me to get the number of threads for the current process.  I am new to the Linux kernel, and so my understanding of it is limited.

Currently, I am trying to iterate through all the `task_struct`s, and compare their thread group leader's PID with the current thread group leader's PID:

```c
// ...
int nthreads = 0;
struct task_struct *task_it;
for_each_process(task_it) {
    if (task_it->group_leader->pid == current->group_leader->pid) {
        nthreads++;
    }
}
// ...
```

However, this doesn't seem to be working (a quick test spawning some pthreads is still giving `1`.  What about the `group_leader` is common to all threads in the same process?

Comment: Wouldn't `/proc/$pid/task/` work for finding how many threads are in the process?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12660720/651394

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is that what the kernel calls a PID (the `pid` field of `task_struct`) is what userspace calls a TID (ie. it's what's returned by `sys_gettid()` and is unique per thread).  What userspace calls a PID is called a TGID in the kernel (for "task group ID") - that's what the `sys_getpid()` syscall returns.

You don't need to actually check the TGID, though - just comparing the `struct task_struct *` pointers is enough:

```
if (task_it->group_leader == current->group_leader) {
```

By the way, you could just iterate over the `thread_group` list that `current` is a member of (with `while_each_thread()`), then you wouldn't need any test at all.  Or even better, just use `get_nr_threads(current)`.

Note that all methods that loop over the task lists need to be wrapped in `rcu_read_lock();` / `rcu_read_unlock();` to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

This chunk of code is a good demonstration.

> The following C program creates a list of all processes in the process
>   table of a node and shows in one column the number of threads for any
>   single process. Using this tool, it was possible to identify that the
>   network daemon created a new thread anytime a network problem
>   occurred. A severe network problem was responsible for the logon
>   problems.

```
#include "sys/param.h"
#include "sys/pstat.h"

int main ( void )
{

  struct pst_status * psa = NULL;   
  struct pst_status * prc = NULL;    
  struct pst_dynamic  psd;
  long                nproc = 0;      
  long                thsum = 0;       
  long                i;                

  if ( pstat_getdynamic(&psd, sizeof(psd), 1, 0) == -1 )
    (void)perror("pstat_getdynamic failed");

  // Get the number of active processes from pst_dynamic 
  nproc  = psd.psd_activeprocs;  
  psa    = (struct pst_status *)malloc(nproc * sizeof(struct pst_status));

  // Read the info about the active processes into the array 'psa' 
  if ( pstat_getproc(psa, sizeof(struct pst_status), nproc, 0) == -1 )
    (void)perror("pstat_getproc failed");

  (void)printf("\n\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
  (void)printf("\n %5s | %5s |%7s| %5s | %s", "PID", "UID", "Threads", "RSS", "Command");
  (void)printf("\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

  // Report the process info as required
  prc = (struct pst_status *)psa;       
  for (i=0; i < nproc; i++) 
  {
    (void)printf("\n %5ld | ", prc->pst_pid);
    (void)printf("%5ld | ", prc->pst_uid);
    (void)printf("%5ld | ", prc->pst_nlwps);
    (void)printf("%5ld | ", prc->pst_rssize);
    (void)printf("%s ", prc->pst_cmd);
    thsum += prc->pst_nlwps;
    ++prc;         
  } 

  (void)printf("\n\n*** %ld processes, %ld threads running\n\n", nproc, thsum);
  (void)free(psa);       
  (void)exit(0);
}
```

Found here:
http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/site/dspp/menuitem.863c3e4cbcdc3f3515b49c108973a801?ciid=060818f70fe0211018f70fe02110275d6e10RCRD

Here's another link using task_struct:
http://tuxthink.blogspot.com/2011/03/using-foreachprocess-in-proc-entry.html

Comment: Is it possible to do this through the task_struct(s), instead of using the `pstat_getproc` function?

Comment: Ok, found another link that uses task_struct.  Looks to do what you need it to. I added the link in the solution above.  Good luck :)